# Combine multiple sql update statements into one statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following update statements that I'm using with MySQL:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test SET Enagement = '800000032764' WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' AND Engagement = '800000026680';
UPDATE billing_info_test SET Enagement = '808000000000' WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' AND Engagement = '807000000041';
UPDATE billing_info_test SET Enagement = '807000000412' WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' AND Engagement = '870000012569';
UPDATE billing_info_test SET Enagement = '808000000223' WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' AND Engagement = '807000000279';
UPDATE billing_info_test SET Enagement = '808000000223' WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' AND Engagement = '807000000282';
UPDATE billing_info_test SET Enagement = '808000000223' WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' AND Engagement = '870000000403';
```

How do I combine all of them into one statement?

Comment: It can be done, but will be verbose and obscure compared to the separated statements. Why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @TheImpaler It's a pretty obvious scalability improvement. _1_ statement is better than _N_.

Comment: You can still batch them.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, by doing exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not exactly the same. When batching you are queueing multiple statements, while the OP want to compose a single one. Both improve scalability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) expression:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
SET Enagement = CASE Enagement
                     WHEN '800000026680' THEN '800000032764'
                     WHEN '807000000041' THEN '808000000000'
                     WHEN ... THEN ...
                END
WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' 
  AND Engagement IN ('800000026680', '807000000041', ...);
```

Comment: you most likely mean `WHERE (LinkedAccountId, Engagement) IN (('123456789101', '800000026680'), ... )` Edit: oh never mind i just noticed `LinkedAccountId` is always the same in the topicstarters example queries.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, when LinkedAccountId is different per Enagement then row constructor is the way to go :)

Comment: Hi one more question. I had to add another LinkedAccountId to the query. Is this statement the same as the individual queries I have in the OP? I think it is, but I would like some confirmation of that, since I am new to this:

Comment: `UPDATE table_name 
SET Engagement = CASE Engagement
     WHEN '800000026680' THEN '800000032764'
     WHEN '807000000041' THEN '808000000000'
     WHEN '870000012569' THEN '807000000412'
     WHEN '807000000279' THEN '808000000223'
     WHEN '807000000282' THEN '808000000223'
     WHEN '870000000403' THEN '808000000223'
    END
WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101'  OR LinkedAccountId = '109876543210'
AND Engagement IN ('800000026680', '807000000041', '870000012569', '807000000279', '807000000282', '870000000403'); `

Comment: @bluethundr If  you want to handle multiple accounts you could use your code but remember about `()`  `WHERE (LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' OR LinkedAccountId = '109876543210') AND Engagement IN ('800000026680', '807000000041', '870000012569', '807000000279', '807000000282', '870000000403');`

Comment: @bluethundr The safer way is to use `IN`: `WHERE LinkedAccountId IN (..., ...) AND Engagement IN (..., ..., ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all six `UPDATE` statements into a single one, as in:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test 
SET Enagement = 
  case when Engagement = '800000026680' then '800000032764'
       when Engagement = '807000000041' then '808000000000'
       when Engagement = '870000012569' then '807000000412'
       when Engagement = '807000000279' then '808000000223'
       when Engagement = '807000000282' then '808000000223'
       when Engagement = '870000000403' then '808000000223'
  end
WHERE LinkedAccountId = '123456789101' 
  and Engagement in ('800000026680', 
                     '807000000041', 
                     '870000012569', 
                     '807000000279', 
                     '807000000282', 
                     '870000000403')
```

If your goal is high performance you can also *batch* all six `UPDATE` statements, something that may be simpler to write and to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid duplicating the column values both in the SET and WHERE clause by using a join:

```
UPDATE billing_info_test b INNER JOIN (
  SELECT '800000026680' Engagement, '800000032764' NewEngagement UNION ALL
  SELECT '807000000041', '808000000000' UNION ALL
  SELECT '870000012569', '807000000412' UNION ALL
  SELECT '807000000279', '808000000223' UNION ALL
  SELECT '807000000282', '808000000223' UNION ALL
  SELECT '870000000403', '808000000223'  
) t ON b.Engagement = t.Engagement 
SET b.Engagement = t.NewEngagement 
WHERE b.LinkedAccountId = '123456789101';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdk8dPyo3DMGZkpVFWTh2e/0).